# merging 2 lazy lists type conflict

Tags: ocaml, lazy-evaluation, lazy-sequences

Why my `merge` function complains about its type ?

Isn't my `x` a `type 'a seq` ?

```
type 'a seq = Stop | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a seq)

let rec linear start step= (*builds a seq starting with 'start'*)
    Cons (start, fun () -> linear (start+step) step)

let rec take n seq = match seq with (*take first n elem from seq*)
| Stop -> []
| Cons (a, f) -> if n < 1 then [] else a::(take (n-1) (f ()))

let rec merge seq1 seq2 = match seq1, seq2 with 
    | Stop, _ -> seq2
    | _, Stop -> seq1
    | Cons(h1, tf1), _ as x -> 
        Cons(h1, fun () -> merge (x) (tf1 ()))

let l1 = linear 1 1
let l2 = linear 100 100 
let l3 = interleave l1 l2
```

I would like to see the right result for

```
take 10 l3
```

> int list = [1; 100; 2; 200; 3; 300; 4; 400; 5; 500]

Another way to write my function (which works) would be

```
let rec merge seq1 seq2 = match seq1 with
| Stop -> Stop
| Cons (h, tf) -> Cons(h, fun () -> merge seq2 (tf ()))
```

but I don't get it , why the first `merge` doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write `(_ as x)` because here, your `as x` catches the whole pattern.

So, what you see as :

```
| Cons(h1, tf1), (_ as x) -> ...
```

is actually parsed as

```
| (Cons(h1, tf1), _) as x -> ...
```

And you could actually write :

```
| Cons(h1, tf1), x -> ...
```

Which is far better ;-)

Or even

```
| Cons(h1, tf1), _ -> Cons(h1, fun () -> merge seq2 (tf1 ()))
```